# Cerrno not working, but strerror working, in Xcode (11.6)

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, c-strings

---

**Edit:** Strerror appears to work. E.g., if errno = ERANGE, it outputs "Result too large".

The problem remains that errno is not changed from 0.

---

In Xcode, I've been trying out `cerrno` and `strerror` with the short code below. Xcode returns

> sqrt(-1) = nan
>
> Undefined error: 0

instead of

> sqrt(-1) = -nan
>
> Numerical argument out of domain,

as does, for example, cpp.sh.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  errno = 0;
  cout << "sqrt(-1) = " << sqrt(-1) << endl;
  cout << strerror(errno) << endl << endl;
       
  return(0); 
}
```

Comment: Primarily to satisfy my curiosity (but may be helpful), can you show us your compiler's value for the `math_errhandling` macro; e.g. add this line: `cout << "math_errhandling = " << math_errhandling << endl;`?

Comment: Hi, it adds "math_errhandling = 2".

Comment: [That explains it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/math_errhandling/) then.

Comment: Well - therein lies the probem! In order to set `errno` that macro has to include `1`. (It should be 3 to conform to C++11, IIRC). But how to fix it ... dunno.

Comment: Can you look through your detailed settings and/or compiler command-line  options to see if the `-fno-math-errno` option is set anywhere; or look through your <cmath> header for a definition of `__NO_MATH_ERRNO__`. Alternatively, try adding `#undef __NO_MATH_ERRNO__` before your `#include...` lines.

Comment: I can't find any such option, but yes, `-fno-math-errno` is probably set. `#undef __NO_MATH_ERRNO__` does not help either.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to check `errno` after an operation, you should always check it, and possibly store it, *immediately after the operation that sets it*. If you perform other function calls in between that check, even something as simple as printing to the terminal, you may be clobbering `errno`.

One possible reason why `errno` is becoming `0` is due to the fact that it is wrapped in the stream expressions, and there's no guarantee that iostream does not indirectly set (or unset) `errno` through its implementation.

If ever you want to check or print the `errno` reason, you will always want to store the result before you print it. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

int main() {

  errno = 0;
  
  // store errno immediately after the computation
  const auto result = std::sqrt(-1);
  const auto err = errno;

  // then print
  std::cout << "sqrt(-1) = " << result << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::strerror(err) << std::endl << std::endl;
       
  return 0; 
}
```

---

**Edit:** From the discussions in the OP's comments, this appears to not be the reason for `errno` not being set -- but rather due to [`math_errhandling` being set to `2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling). I am keeping this answer here for archival reasons, since the code in the original post could just as easily be seeing this result for the reasons described here.

Comment: My bad; not too long after posting this I saw the discussion about `math_errhandling` being responsible. This isn't the right answer for your particular problem, but I'll still keep this answer up though since this is a different possible source for why `errno` may not be what you'd expect it to be (in case anyone else stumbles onto this question)